# tvOS UIImageView Focus Shadow Clipped

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, tvos

I have a UICollectionViewCell in a UICollectionView containing two components

- 1 x UIImageView
- 1 x UIView

The UIView would ideally contain a couple of labels, and has the following properties set as default:

- `backgroundColor = .clear`
- `isHidden = true`

The UICollectionView has `clipsToBounds` set to `false`.

In the `delegate` of the UICollectionView, I am using the `didUpdateFocusIn` function to determine which cell will receive focus next, and un-hide the UIView.

As the UIImageView has the `adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused` set to `true`, there is a drop-shadow drawn by tvOS when it automatically applies the zoom + parallex effect.

As can be see in the two pictures below (the second picture has the UIView's `backgroundColor` set to `.black` for clarity), the shadow is clipped by the empty space belonging to the UIView in the cell beside it, even though the UIView is already hidden.

Is there some way that I can resolve this?

**Edit:** Have added a third image which shows the shadow behaving perfectly when the UIView is totally removed from the .xib.

[image: UIView with *clear* backgroundColor]

[image: UIView with *black* backgroundColor]

[image: UICollectionViewCell without UIView]

Comment: Have you set `clipsToBounds` on the cell to `false`?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez yes, I have, but unfortunately, it does not help.

Comment: I would suggest using the View Hierarchy Inspector, when you run the app it's the icon that's a rectangle in front of another rectangle, two icons left of the location icon in the debug bar of Xcode. You can also find it in the menu bar: `Debug -> View Debugging -> Capture View Hierarchy`

Comment: @EmilioPelaez thanks for the suggestion! I was indeed using the Inspector previously to check on the view hierarchy, but it was in the midst of preparing a screenshot for you that I stumbled upon the cause of the issue. Will post my answer below!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that I'm a bumbling fool.

I forgot that I had set the bottom constraint of the `UIImageView` to be anchored to the top of the UIView that was below it.

The net result of hiding the `UIView` caused the `UIImageView` to seek out the bottom of the `UICollectionViewCell`, and that caused the clipping issues.

I have now constrained the `UIImageView` to a fixed height, and the problem has been resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Since tvOS 11, there is no need to bind your view constraints to the UIImageView constraints to get that effect.

You can get that effect making use of the new property overlayContentView of UIImageView.

Link to the documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview/2882128-overlaycontentview

A more elaborated explanation can be found from the minute 15:00 of the following WWDC video:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/209/

If the method offered by Apple to get this effect, is not enough for your specific case, I also recommend this great third party library which basically allows getting a Parallax effect in any UIView.

https://github.com/PGSSoft/ParallaxView